# How to save xrandr options?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, xrandr

In order to get full RGB output (0-255) on my Intel UHD630 integrated graphics I have to run this command at every reboot:

```
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

Is there a way to save this so that it runs automatically when X starts?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You'll have to define these settings in /etc/X11/xorg.conf , specific syntax is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a command directly at every reboot using `cron` jobs
First, create a small script and save it.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

Open `terminal` and run

```
crontab -e
```

Then type

```
@reboot /path/to/script/<scriptname>.sh
```

Replace the path and the scriptname

Finally, enable `cron` service

```
systemctl enable crond.service
```

Comment: I created the script and put it in "Startup applications" instead of crontab, seems to work fine on reboot